# Centos7 shows > instead of <

Tags: centos7, nano

I'm experiencing a very odd problem.

I've installed `CentOS7` and I'm configuring php, so I wanted to create a phpinfo file.

I'm typing `<` to open the tag, however the screen shows `>`.

Is anybody familiar with this problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Removed unnecessary detail, and formatted.

Comment: CentOS is an operating system, not a text editor.